# Why The Output Of "git log" Is Different In Terminal And execSync In node.js

Tags: node.js, git

I have a newly created repository. When I execute the command:

```sh
git log --no-color --pretty=oneline
```

in the Terminal, I get:

```sh
d4288625b31ad486941d6f4848054dcd96487687 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Initial commit
```

which is what we expect naturally.

If I execute the same command within the node.js:

```js
const {execSync} = require('child_process')
const cmd = `git log --no-color --pretty=oneline`
const commitlog = execSync(cmd, {encoding: 'utf8'})
console.log(commitlog)
```

I get:

```sh
d4288625b31ad486941d6f4848054dcd96487687 Initial commit
```

as the output. As you see the part inside the parentheses cut off.

I've also tested this in a mature repository but still the same happens and it doesn't relate to the maxBuffer setting in node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man git log`:

> --no-decorate, --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
> [...]  If auto is specified, then if the output is going
> to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no
> ref names are shown. The default option is short.

So it looks like somehow `--decorate=auto` is set in your case? Add `--decorate=short` to get deterministic output.

Comment: More generally, `git log` is what the Git system calls a *porcelain command*. Porcelain commands tailor their output based on user configuration settings and other items, including `log.decorate` which defaults to `auto`. In contrast, Git has *plumbing commands* which are meant to be run from other programs and produce consistent results. Unfortunately there is no plumbing equivalent of `git log`—ideally it would have an option, as `git status` does, to make it usable from programs, but instead you just have to know all the possible quirks in each version of Git.

Comment: Adding `--decorate=short` resolved the issue but I really have no idea why or how is it different inside a node.js script. Thank you anyway.

Comment: *"I really have no idea why or how is it different inside a node.js script"* When you run it inside a node script via `exec_sync`, the process' standard output isn't connected to the terminal. And the man page says that no ref names are displayed if the output is not going to a terminal. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio